# Removing html emoji for xml 1.0

Tags: c#, xml

I'm missing something badly so i decided to ask for some help.

So i have xml ISO encoded with incorrect chars - escaped html for example �� (and here with space after &,  & #xd83d;& #xdc4d;

My first thought was to un-escape those and use one of many regexes to clean xml

```
string test = @"&#xd83d;&#xdc4d;";
var outText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(test);
```

Nothing changed, so next try was to read this as bytes

```
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(Message);
        byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso, utf8 , isoBytes);
        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utfBytes);
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do I understand that correctly: You've got a rather big `html` file which contains invalid entities? What do you want: "repair" invalid entities, get rid of them, replace them? It would help to show a tiny `html` example with one or two *broken* entities and the expected output.

Comment: It is database dump (with html pages inside) that is in XML 1.0, but it is invalid XML... I want to remove them and be done with that.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear... A *data base dump*? Just a (binary) bunch of characters? If this is saved as `NVARCHAR` a blank - as any other character will be shown as two bytes...  Show an example...

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string testHtml = @"<head><title>&#xd83d;&#xdc4d;</title></head><body>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</body>";
    var output = Remove(testHtml);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.Read();
}

private static string Remove(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex("\\&#.*?\\;");
    var output = regex.Replace(input, string.Empty);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: but this will also remove valid XML chars like carriage return &#xd,etc? we are talking about xml that weights few GB so not a chance to test what was removed